# How to retrieve a collection of fields in Glass model?

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

Is it possible to retrieve a collection of fields as a property of a mapped glass model ? For example, I have a "Product" item in Sitecore with a collection of custom "Product Attribute" fields. I'd like to be able to access these fields as a collection through which I can enumerate, without explicitly naming the fields in my glass model. This way I can then add more attributes and enumerate them in code, without changing the glass model code.

Something like the following:

```
[SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Fields)]
public virtual IEnumerable<something> Attributes { get; set; }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: When you say "Product Attribute" fields, I presume they are actually other Sitecore items located elsewhere in the tree (selectable via a multilist or similar)?

Comment: They are custom field types which are fields of the Product template. They are not child items.

Comment: If they are fields on your template (default or custom) then other than using reflection I am not aware of any way (and I would avoid the reflection route). Perhaps use some sort of code generation tools instead, or rethink your design.

Comment: @epikphail Maybe change the Information Architecture and force them to select this items in a Treelist or multilist if it possible. By doing this it will be possible to get them as a list and your code will work :)

Comment: @nsgocev that would be sensible, but there are some other requirements which make this a preferable approach. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @epikphail then custom handler implementation should be your way to go ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any more specifics, it sounds like you may want to implement a [Glass Mapper data handler](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial19) via `AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper` for your custom type.

Comment: Thanks I will investigate that.

Comment: This was a good solution. I wrote a custom data handler which returned a collection of Product Attribute fields. It was necessary to add a text field to the Product template in order to convince Glass to do the mapping.

Answer (score -2):

You would actually need something like

[SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Fields(Filters = "*.customAttributes", Order ="..."))]

because you have to define the order of the collection and a way how to recognise the items to be included into the collection. Better don't do it and look out for a cleaner solution.

For example you could specify the product attributes as child items or just give the product attributes real names and reference them in the sublayout/view.

Comment: Where did `SitecoreInfoType.Fields` come from? It's not in the list of valid enum values for [SitecoreInfoType](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/Configuration/SitecoreInfoType.cs)

Comment: It's just a creatively invented pseudo code.Thought I've mentioned it.

Comment: Unfortunately creatively invented pseudo codes don't solve problems :(